# How to choose Class mediator or Script mediator in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: javascript, xml, wso2, wso2-esb

In my opinion both of them have same capacity to do the transformation.
Class and Script all implementation of the MessageContext.

[In Class Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Class+Mediator),

We can using the package org.apache.axiom.om for manipulation of XML.

[In Script Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Script+Mediator#),

We can using JavaScript E4X or Ruby REXML to manipulation XML.
One thing in there, from my knowledge, we can't debug JS step by step. This may cause inconvenience in development.

I think Class and Script are so similar. My question is, how to choose Class mediator or Script mediator? 
Can anyone share their ideas about how to choose?

Answer (score 0):

Class Mediator is an extension point in WSO2 ESB. If you can't achieve your usecase by using any inbuilt mediators (script, payload factory, xslt..etc) or if you see any performance drop in using any inbuilt mediators, then you should go for a class mediator to cater your requirements.